# Terraform Import - Is the Resource Label critical?

Tags: azure, terraform, azureportal

Our terraform remote state file in Azure has been completely destroyed and we're now faced with the challenge of recreating the state file from scratch. My option is to use the Terraform import command, using the following simple syntax:

```
terraform import <Terraform Resource Name>.<Resource Label> <Azure Resource ID>
```

To import the existing resource group for example, I will create the following configuration in a main.tf file.

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version="1.39.0"
}

# create resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg"{
    name = "rg-terraform"
    location = "uksouth"
}
```

Now, the problem I have is as follows:

When the existing Azure resources were originally created, they were assigned  names that used an extremely complex naming convention, with some characters even being randomly generated. To further compound matters, they were all unique and there are hundreds of them. All would have been rosy if they were assigned a simplistic name like "main", as is used commonly in a lot of Terraform examples, but unfortunately, that's not the case.

My question therefore, is this:

1. When putting together my main.tf configuration file to be used for the Import, is it an absolute requirement that my "Resource Label" (given in my Import command) has to match the original "Resource Label" name from when the resource was created?
2. If it is a mandatory requirement, is there any way I could retrieve the original "Resource Label" from Azure in the same way that I can for instance obtain the "Azure Resource ID" from the Azure Portal or even an Az CLI query?
3. How can I ensure any child resources such as Subnets are included in the Import, without having to trawl manually through the Azure Portal to identify each one of them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No, absolutely not. Choose whatever you want.
2. No, Azure generally does not know about this label, it is something terraform internal.
3. Unfortunately you need to import each and every resource manually and separately.

Have you made absolutely sure the current state file is lost? The storage location was not versioned? Does no developer still have a local copy of the state file laying around?

Comment: luk2302 you're an absolute life-saver. I can't believe the speed with which you've answered my queries and you have no idea what it means to me. It arrived at the very minute I was about to enter a meeting to provide some feedback on this issue. You are an absolute gem !!

Comment: @hitman126 You can also upvote his answer to show appreciation and recommend it as a good answer.

Comment: Another question. A large number of our resources were created using modules. Reviewing some of the other state files that we fortunately still have available, I've spotted that there are several module.* block entries. Therefore, my question on that is, should my main.tf file used for the import, explicitly reference a module folder, or does that not matter and it makes little difference whether or not the state file references a module?

Comment: @luk2302, yes sadly the state file is lost completely. I've only just joined the project myself and the lack of versioning on the blob storage was one of the major disappointments which I've since rectified. Local copies don't exist either, as the resources were all provisioned through Azure Pipelines and nothing was developed locally.

Comment: @hitman126 modules are once again something terraform internal, Azure does not know about it, they are only there to make the terraform code a little bit more manageable. If you now import resources you can decide to import them into sub modules or just have them top level, makes no difference to the import. It really depends on wether or not you want to have modules in your terraform code or not.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for the excellent feedback. It means one less thing to worry about. I'm frankly not at all fussed over whether or not we retain the module references and as a matter of fact, shelving that idea entirely will make my life a lot easier and so I'll import everything into the top-level.